# Direct deployment PHP files on OpenShift

Tags: php, openshift

Is it possible to deploy php files on Openshift directly? (That is, not via git).

Most of my php files are single page files and I'm looking for a way to SFTP directly into Openshift. 
I am able to login via Filezilla, but when I try to transfer files into directories like app-deployment or app-root etc, the file gets deleted.

Openshift folder structure:

[image: Openshift folder structure]

So, how can I upload PHP files directly?

Comment: Why would you want to bypass your version control system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many trials, I found that its actually possible.

Inside this folder: `app-roots/repo/myfile.php`

Answer (score 1):

OpenShift has a few blog posts on the topic:

- [Using FileZilla and SFTP on Windows with OpenShift](https://blog.openshift.com/using-filezilla-and-sftp-on-windows-with-openshift/)
- [Getting started with SFTP and OpenShift (Using Netbeans)](https://blog.openshift.com/getting-started-with-sftp-and-openshift/)